# Python function looping only once

Tags: python, loops

This function only loops once, why?

```
def loop(f, n):         #f repeats n times
    if n<=0:
        return
    else:
        loop(f, n-1)
```

I use a print function for f, and 5 to repeat 5 times

Comment: How do you call this function and how do you know how many times it loops (no print, no return value)?

Comment: loop(print function, 5) so I used a print function for a return value to be displayed 5 times

Comment: Also, wouldn't it be simpler to write it as `def loop(f, n): if n > 0: loop(f, n - 1)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you mean to call f() before (or after) the recursive call

```
def loop(f, n):         #f repeats n times
    if n<=0:
        return
    else:
        f()             # don't forget to call f()
        loop(f, n-1)
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I'm still a newbie

Comment: @30trix, how have you defined f?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly and you are just trying to repeat something n times, you don't need to use a recursive function.

For example:

```
n = 5
for i in xrange(5):
    # do whatever should happen  here
    # i is the current iterator
    print i
```

Comment: Use `xrange()` instead of `range()` - `xrange()` is lazy and only returns one value at a time. `range()` has to compute and store the entire list of numbers, which uses a good deal of memory when doing things like `for n in range(100000000)`.

Comment: Li-aung Yip is right, xrange is more efficient here - have edited my code.